# Spring Boot - postForEntity(): what is content type of the response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am attempting to set up and run integration tests on a set of Spring Boot microservices that communicate via HTTP REST. I am using the Citrus Framework for the integration test framework.

I have a test scenario that involves one "master" service calling two other services to do work. My test has the calls to start the process and "mock" the worker services. I'll include source below.

I'm running into an issue where I get an exception that seems to indicate that a message the test is expecting to receive (as `application/json`) is coming through as `text/plain` and it cannot find a message converter to use. The odd thing is that the message that's is being received **should** be JSON (or least *look* like JSON).

I encountered a similar issue on the sending end (the POSTer), where Citrus was having a problem with receiving a message. I traced it down to the fact that I had not been setting any HTTP headers, specifically `Accept` and `Content-Type`. Once I set these appropriately, Citrus was happy with what it received.

The service code:

```
HttpEntity<GenerateRouteCommand> entity =
    (HttpEntity<GenerateRouteCommand>) HttpEntityBuilder.createHttpEntity(...);
ResponseEntity<GenerateRouteStatus> response =
    rgTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, GenerateRouteStatus.class);
```

The exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class edu.mit.ll.mission_services.messages.GenerateRouteStatus] and content type [text/plain;charset=utf-8]                                                                                             
        at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:121)                                              
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:994)                                                
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:977)                                                
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:737)                                                                                  
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:670)                                                                                    
        at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:445)                                                                              
        at edu.mit.ll.mission_services.service.mission_planner.service.MissionPlanner.postGenerateRoute(MissionPlanner.java:214)                                         
        at edu.mit.ll.mission_services.service.mission_planner.service.MissionPlanner.planMission(MissionPlanner.java:144)                                               
        at edu.mit.ll.mission_services.service.mission_planner.controller.MissionPlannerController$Runner.executeTask(MissionPlannerController.java:51)                  
        at edu.mit.ll.mission_services.common.util.ITask.run(ITask.java:37)                                                                                              
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)                                                                               
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)                                                                               
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The entity that's being sent in the POST request has the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers set to `application/json`. I think I'm OK there. The stack trace above seems to be saying that the response message either has no headers set (or set to the wrong values) and since the test case expects JSON, fails the test.

When these services are run "normally" (i.e. not being driven via Citrus), everything works fine. No problems that I've been able to discern.

Comment: You can debug for: `ResponseEntity<String> response = rgTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, String.class);` to see what you are receiving exactly

Comment: Helpful tip. I used this to verify that a JSON string was being returned, but that indeed, the content type is `text/plain`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what I needed to do to set the expected content type of `application/json` for a message returned from a mocked server in Citrus. I was missing the following statement:

```
.contentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType())
```

Some context:

```
// Set route assessor to return response.
runner.http(builder -> builder
    .server(raServer)
    .send()
    .response(HttpStatus.OK)
    .messageType(MessageType.JSON)
    .contentType(ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType())
    .payload(new ClassPathResource("templates/assess-route-status.json")));
```

Evidently, it defaults to `text/plain` if not specified.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently ran into this issue with spring-boot twice while trying to decode REST Respones.  I solved this issue by explicitly setting `HttpMessageConverters` on the `RestTemplate`.

If I were you I would debug and see what the content of the response actually looks like. If it is JSON try using `GsonHttpMessageConverter` or if it really is just text, try `StringHttpMessageConverter`.  Alternatively add both to the `RestTemplate` via the following:

```
private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplateBuilder()
        .messageConverters(Lists.newArrayList(new GsonHttpMessageConverter(GsonHelper.getInstance()), new StringHttpMessageConverter()))
        .build();
```

If neither of these converters appear to solve your exception, take a look at all the different implementations of the `HttpMessageConverter` interface and deduce which one would suite your specific case.  There are a fair number of implementations implementing this interface.

Comment: I reviewed my REST template factory and verified that I am adding the following converters: `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` and `StringHttpMessageConverter`. This code was already in place.

Comment: I think this is an issue with Citrus Framework (or probably how I'm using it). I did some experimentation and verified that when the services are run normally, that the content type is `application/json` as expected. When I attempt to run the Citrus integration test, the content type is `text/plain`. I need to figure out why.